# Postgres error: operator does not exist: text ~~ bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, casting

I have the following snippet to create a query:

```
predicate.add(criteriaBuilder.like(map.get("value"), variable.get("value")));
```

`variable.get("value")` returns a `String`, and `map.get("value")` returns an `Expression<String>`.

The generated query looks like the following snippet:

```
where variables.VARIABLE_VALUE like $2
```

The database logs show the following error (character 1570 corresponds to the like expression above):

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ~~ bigint at character 1570
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

`VARIABLE_VALUE` is of type `text` in the database and the given parameter `$2` is supposed to be `String` not a `BIGINT`.

I don't know why is the `variable.get("value")` output transformed to `BIGINT` instead of `String`.

**Settings:**

> Database: Postgres 12.2
>
> Hibernate Dialect: PostgreSQL94Dialect
>
> Driver postgresql-42.2.11.jar
>
> Hibernate version: hibernate-jpa-2.1-api

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code snippet that allow to reproduce your problem. It is not clear what are `predicate`, `map`, `variable` variables mean?

Comment: And this `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` is not a hibernate version. This is just jpa version that hibernate implements.

Comment: Unrelated, but: tables have **columns** not "variables"

Comment: @SternK it is actually criteriaBuilder.like(map.get("value"), variable.get("value") that poses problem. A String value is converted to BigInt and I don't understand why?